# Website appears differently on different browsers/systems

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, web

totally confused about this as there doesn't seem to be anything 'wrong' with the code. I've asked a few people to check the site and I keep getting different answers. Ranging from the scrolling text appearing to scroll in upon loading (which I obviously don't want) to displaying no pictures :/

Anyone able to help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>WEBSITE TITLE</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/page.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<h1>WEBSITE TITLE</h1>
<h2><a href="mailto:EMAIL@ADDRESS.COM">EMAIL@ADDRESS.COM</a></h2>

<ul id="arrows">
<li><a id="arrow1" href="http://www.facebook.com">Arrow<span></span></a></li>
<li><a id="arrow2" href="http://twitter.com">Arrow2<span></span></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="photo01"></div>

<div id="navcontainer">

<ul id="navlist">

<li><span>List</span><ul>
<li><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">6</a></li>
<li><a href="#">7</a></li>
<li><a href="#">8</a></li>
<li><a href="#">9</a></li>
<li><a href="#">10</a></li>
<li><a href="#">11</a></li>
<li><a href="#">12</a></li>
<li><a href="#">13</a></li>
<li><a href="#">14</a></li>
<li><a href="#">15</a></li>

</ul></li></ul>
</div><!-- end #navcontainer -->



</div><!-- end #container -->

</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS looks like this:

```
body {
/*margin:0;*/     margin:10px;
background-image:url(background.png);
background-attachment:fixed;
font-family:'hoefler text',georgia,'times new roman',serif;
}

a {
color:#dadada;
text-decoration:none;
}
a:visited,a:hover {
color:#fff;
}
a:active {
color:#000;
}
a {
outline:0;
}

#container {
/*width:1000px;*/                       min-width:1000px;
                                        padding-bottom:20px;
/*margin:140px auto 0;*/ 
}

div #photo01
     {      
             float:left;
     position:absolute;
             width: 690px;
             height: 550px;
                                               margin-top:150px;
                                               margin-bottom:20px;
                                               margin-left:880px;

             background-image: url(img_01.jpg);
             background-repeat: no-repeat;
             /*background-position: 200px 300px;*/
     }

h1,h2 {
position:absolute;
/*top:225px;*/ top:235px;
left:50px;
z-index:2;
/*width:1000px;*/ width:720px;
padding-top:25px;
margin:0;
color:#dadada;
font-weight:normal;
font-size:1.85em;
letter-spacing:0.2em;
line-height:1.1em;
text-transform:uppercase;
background-image:url(background.png);
}
h2 { 
                    width:500px;                     
/*top:290px;*/      top:300px;
padding-top:20px;
font-size:1.0em;
                     background-image:url(background.png);
}

#arrows {                       
float:left;
width:64px;
padding:0;
/*margin-top:250px;
margin-bottom:50px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-left:-150px;*/                          margin-top:402px;
                                               margin-bottom:200px;
                                               margin-left:50px;

list-style-type:none;
}
#arrows a {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:64px;
height:64px;
/*margin-bottom:10px;*/margin-bottom:5px;
text-indent:-9999px;
overflow:hidden;
background-image:url(arrows.png);
}
#arrows span {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:64px;
height:64px;
background-image:url(arrows.png);
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
#arrows span:hover {
opacity:1;
}
#arrow1 {
background-position:0 0;
}
#arrow1 span {
background-position:0 -64px;
}
#arrow2 {
background-position:-64px 0;
}
#arrow2 span {
background-position:-64px -64px;
}

#navcontainer {
clear:both;
overflow-x:hidden;
}

#navlist {
float:left;
line-height:30px;  
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style-type:none;
color:#dadada;
font-size:0.65em;
letter-spacing:0.2em;
line-height:1.1em;
text-align:left;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

#navlist:first-child {
position:relative;
cursor:pointer;
}

#navlist span {
position:absolute;
z-index:1; 
width:100px;
line-height:40px;
padding-left:50px; 
background-image:url(background.png);
color:#dadada;
}

#navlist ul {
padding:0;
margin:0 0 0 -1300px; 
list-style-type:none;
-webkit-transition:all 2s ease;
-moz-transition:all 2s ease;
-o-transition:all 2s ease;
}

#navlist ul li {
float:left;
margin:0 3px;
}

#navlist:first-child:hover ul{
margin:0 0 0 150px; 
color:#dadada;
}

#navlist a {
display:block;
line-height:40px;
padding:0 8px;
color:#dadada;
-webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition:all 0.5s ease;
}

#navlist a:hover {
color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is. I've loaded it into JS Fiddle so we have something to go off of. Could you give me more details on the issue and if it's specific to a certain type of browser?

http://jsfiddle.net/eNyqK/

Comment: Thanks Justine - it seems that Chrome is causing issues with it. I have installed Chrome myself here and the page loads with a white background first and then loads the background image. Also, the scrolling text can be seen scrolling in upon loading. This does not happen in Firefox however.

Comment: Hi John - Do you have this page posted publicly somewhere so that I can see your background image issue?